# How to Handle default radio option to other radio option

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, radio-button

I have 2 radio options for Address fields like yes or no, by default US Address option selected for this Zip code field will display, When I click radio option on 'no' then zip code field will be hidden. So I need the code to handle the radio options for above scenario.

// US address - this is working fine as default radio selected  to"yes"

```
      WebElement radio = driver.findElement(By.id("usid"));
    radio.isSelected();
       driver.findElement(By.id("uszipcode")).sendKeys("1234");
      driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();

    //non US Address- (having issues here)
      driver.findElement(By.id("nonusid")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
```

I should be able to click from default radio option "yes" to "no" then submit should work

Answer (score 0):

Try if..else block to achieve that.

```
WebElement radio = driver.findElement(By.id("usid"));
        if(radio.isSelected())
        {
            WebElement radio1 = driver.findElement(By.id("usid of NO radio Button"));
            radio1.click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
        }
        else
        {   
           driver.findElement(By.id("uszipcode")).sendKeys("1234");
           driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
        }
```

Comment: I tried above but script is not continuing to click on "no" radio option. Please suggest if I can try anything else as I don't see any issues in console also like no such element exception like that.

Comment: You mean it is going to else block not if?

Comment: Can you post the url or html?

Comment: This is the values I have  Non USA: <input id="nonusBasedid" type="radio" name="forgotid-usBased" value="Foreign">

USA: <input id="usBasedid" type="radio" checked="" name="forgotid-usBased" value="USA"> (This is default set to yes")

Comment: Are you trying to click on the `Non USA` radio? I see you are not using the correct `id` to select the radio.

Comment: I have mentioned sample ids, not the real ids. I don't see any issues with the ids. If I try with thread.sleep option before and after click, does that works?

Comment: @Hi2AP : Based on your example it is going to if block and clicked the radio button.I have checked now.Can you provide your url to understand what is wrong there?

Comment: @KajalKundu- There was an issue with id, tried with xpath now script is working. I appreciate your help and Thank you !